VUE 3 Transitions on Custom Component not working for some reason
I’m making a web app with Vue 3 , in the menu, each menu button loads a component.
My intention is that every time a component loads it should have a transition. The problem is, it seems to just not work. If I add "mode = "out in"" it just stays blank regardless of which button I click. I've tried the transition with other basic components (<H> <div>) and it works, just not with the components.
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />

  <div class="page-wrapper" style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-2" id="green" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
          <div class="sidebar-header">
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-links">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons"
              @click="component = 'MainHomeComponent'">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-house" id="home-icon"></i><br />Inicio
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons"
              @click="component = 'MetricMainComponent'">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-table-cells" id="metrics-icon"></i><br />Metricos
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-ranking-star" id="ranking-icon"></i><br />Ranking
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-chart" id="trends-icon"></i><br />Tendencia
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-question" id="status-icon"></i><br />Estatus
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-user" id="support-icon"></i><br />Soporte
            </button>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="menu-buttons">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-gear" id="admin-icon"></i><br />Admin
            </button>
            <br /><br />
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-footer">
            <div class="user-space">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="logout-button">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="logout-icon">logout</span><br />Cerrar Sesion
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10" style="padding: 0">
          <transition name="fade">
            <div class="main-content-container">
              <component :is="component"></component>
            </div>
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style src="../css/Home.css"></style>
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
import MainHomeComponent from "../components/MainHomeComponent.vue";
import MetricMainComponent from "../components/MetricMainComponent.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MainHomeComponent,
    MetricMainComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      component: MainHomeComponent,
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>


Wonder if I'm overlooking something? I've seen that transitions won’t work on more than one root node.
But, this is one of the component I've tried to load with transition:
<template>
  <div class="top-bar" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="welcome-message">
      <header class="header">
        <h5 class="title-text" style="font-size: 35px;">Métricos</h5>
        <p class="subtitle-text" style="font-size: 25px;">Actualiza los métricos de las diferentes categorias.</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="metrics-page-wrapper">
    
  </div>
</template>

<style src="../css/MetricMainComponent.css"></style>



I’ve tried to load components dynamically with transitions.

Try with a key: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#transitions-with-the-key-attribute

If I am not mistaken, the dynamic component must be a direct descendant of the Transition element.
<Transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
  <component :is="view"></component>
</Transition>

Please check the examples in the Transition API reference.
